# Tear off using extjs

Tags: extjs

I am using ExtJs 4.2 in my project and I am stuck with one requirement. Actually what we want is to open a new window which will the replica of widget from where it has been requested.
We are able to open it by using window.open(), but please suggest me the way with which i can maintain the same state such as various values in various components etc. present in parent widget.
Moreover this child window should be independent from the application.
Is there any way of doing it ??

Comment: Depends on how you want to store your values.. a database, a storage or a singleton class.

Comment: the case here is , suppose we have a drop down on a widget and i select , say 'ABC', from the list of data. Now when i open new replica of this widget in a new window i should get the dropdown in the child window prepopulated with the value 'ABC'. Please let me know if we can achieve this.

Comment: was the answer below helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.state.CookieProvider 
and browser state management example: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/state/state.html